# Alert message is not displayed in Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I do not understand why Ajax is not calling success or error in this function:

```js
function get_cust_key(custid) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/Test/index.php/getCustomerkey/' + custid,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    sucsess: function(result) {
      alert("success");
      console.log(result)
    },
    error: function(result) {
      alert("error");
      consloe.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

I should get success or error alert message but I get nothing. If i make non existing url like:

```
url: 'http://localhost/Test/index.php/something/'+custid,
```

then i get  error alert message.

with correct link it seams to be working. If I use debugger i can see that link with "custid" returns result (200) with correct (expected) json data, but for some reason this result is not initiating success call and I do not get success alert message. In console log I do not get any error messages. I have tried this code:

```js
$.post('http://localhost/Test/index.php/getCustomerkey/' + custid, function(data, status) {
  alert("Data: " + data['data']['0']['custkey'] + "\nStatus: " + status);
  console.log(data);
});
```

For some reason it alert window works, I also get data from json status==success.

Any Ideas why my top code not working, why I do not get success or error alert...

Comment: `sucsess` <-- whoops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [epascarello noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63138163/alert-message-is-not-displayed-in-ajax-request#comment111649242_63138163), there's a typo in the configuration, try to substitute `sucsess` with `success`.